# Playwright c# how to select one of multiple identical elements

Tags: playwright

Im using playwright with C# and a trying to do the following:

I have two elements with the same locator.

I want to be able to locate one of them by position, i.e 1st or 2nd found.

when do the following:

```
var nameField = page.Locator("div[data-key='Name']");
await nameField.FillAsync("");
```

I get the error:

Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException : Error: strict mode violation: "div[data-ph-key='Name']" resolved to 2 elements:

Ive tried the following based on the playwright documentation:

```
var nameField = page.Locator("div[data-ph-key='Name'] >> nth=0");
```

this results in the element resolved to 2 elements error:

also tried this

```
 var nameField = page.Locator("div[data-key='Name']");
 await nameField.First.FillAsync("");
```

which returns the same error

How can do a simple select the nth element found and interact with it?
Is there something similar to selenium's IWebelements where I would put all the matching elements in a collection and interact with the desired one based on its index position?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this works:

```
var nameField = page.Locator("div[data-key='Name']")
await nameField.Nth(0).FillAsync("");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can check for multiple matching locators like this:

```
var nameField = page.Locator("div[data-key='Name']");
if (await namefiled.CountAsync() > 1)
{
    // Logic for choosing specific locator goes here...
}
```

If you happen to know the index of the specific element you want, you can select it like this:

```
var locatorIndex = 0;
var nameField = await page.Locator("div[data-key='Name']").Nth(locatorIndex);
```

But your code would be less brittle if you chose the locator using a parent / child relationship:

```
var nameField = page.Locator("div[data-key='ParentName']div[data-key='ChildName']");
```